# A potentially dark fantasy novel set in Minnesota with magic monsters in it

Tags: story-identification, novel, horror

I remember reading this book when I was about 12 or 13, so it's a middle-school reading level and published around 2005 or earlier.

It's about a group of kids living in a wooded Minnesotan town who, after some set of events, find their world has magic monsters in it.

I tagged it as horror because I remember the book having darker tones when I was a kid. I'm also pretty sure the conventional fantasy creatures were a bit more twisted than their Harry Potter counterparts, and they were out to seriously hurt the kids in this book.

There also is/was an IRL insurance company named after the city in which the story is set.

Comment: Welcome to the site! Great start. Take a look at this [guide](http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/a/9337/68872) to help jog your memory and see if you can edit in any more details.

Comment: In the story, the insurance company exists with the same name? Or it matches an IRL insurance company's name?

Comment: The insurance company is / was IRL

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's a book series titled ["*The Grey Griffins*"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grey_Griffins) first published in 2006. The first novel was "*Revenge of the Shadow King*".

> The Grey Griffins series follows the story of four sixth graders who live in the fictional city of Avalon, Minnesota. These four friends formed a secret order named The Order of the Grey Griffins, consisting of, Grayson Maximillian "Max" Sumner III (the leader) and his friends: Natalia Romanov (the marshal), Ernie Tweeny (the steward), and Harley Eisenstein (the warden). In *The Revenge of the Shadow King*, the Grey Griffins discover a link between their 'innocent' card game (Round Table) and a magic book (the Codex Spiritus) which Max discovers in his grandmother's attic.

So the town is fictional, however, there is a real life insurance company called "Avalon Insurance".